# check for error with shell script with multiple commands on one line

Tags: shell

I'm trying to catch the error code of a failed command in my shell script on Linux. In this case my ffprobe command:

```
#!/bin/sh
    videoduration=$(ffprobe -loglevel error -show_format myfile.avi | grep duration | cut -d= -f2)
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
       echo "ERROR"
       exit 1
    fi
echo $videoduration
```

If I change that command to give a bogus file name:

```
#!/bin/sh
    videoduration=$(ffprobe -loglevel error -show_format myfile.av | grep duration | cut -d= -f2)
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
       echo "ERROR"
       exit 1
    fi
echo $videoduration
```

The error code is useless here because technically the status code is still 0. The code will still have a successful `grep` and `cut`. How can I keep this command in a single variable but exit with error if ffprobe command fails?

**EDIT:** I'd prefer a non shell specific answer if there is one. Also the proposed duplicate covers a similar case but the only potential option here is to create a temp file like so:

```
f=`mktemp`
(ffprobe ...; echo $?>$f) | ...
e=`cat $f` #error in variable e
rm $f
```

Seems like a hack creating a temp file? If this is the only option how would I store this in a variable?

Comment: I don't think so. I'd prefer a non shell specific answer. I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that even though the `ffprobe` command fails, the `cut` does not and returns a zero exitcode. The exit status of a pipe is the exit status of the *last* command, unless your shell has means to change this behaviour to return the exit status of the first command to fail. You can do this with `set -o pipefail` in `bash`/`ksh`:

```
$ false | cut -d= -f2; echo $?
0
$ set -o pipefail 
$ false | cut -d= -f2; echo $?
1
```